# How can I cast a DateField() + TimeField() to local time in a Django QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My model as these fields:

- date = `models.DateField()`
- start_time = `models.TimeField()`
- end_time = `models.TimeField()`

I would like to annotate the queryset with `start_datetime` and `end_datetime`, like so:

```py
class SessionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_datetimes(self):
        return self.annotate(
            start_datetime=ExpressionWrapper(
                F('date') + F('start_time'),
                output_field=models.DateTimeField()
            ),
            end_datetime=ExpressionWrapper(
                F('date') + F('end_time'),
                output_field=models.DateTimeField()
            ),
        )
```

However, the output field in the query results in a naive datetime:

```py
>>> Session.objects.with_datetimes()[0].start_datetime
<<< datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 20, 17, 0)
```

I would like the dates to be localized within the query.

I tried wrapping the above expressions in `django.db.models.functions.Cast()`, with `output_field=DateTimeField()`, but it casts to UTC and not the local timezone.

Essentially what I need is the equivalent of the Postgres `at time zone` feature to convert a naive time to localtime. Is there a way to do that in Django?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can use any Postgres function by writing a custom django database function.

Here is a custom django database function for the equivalent of the Postgres `at time zone`.

###### Django 4.0

```py
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F, Func
from django.db import models


class AtTimeZone(Func):
    function = 'AT TIME ZONE'
    template = "%(expressions)s %(function)s '%(timezone)s'"


class SessionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_datetimes(self):
        return self.annotate(
            start_datetime=ExpressionWrapper(
                F('date') + F('start_time'),
                output_field=models.DateTimeField()
            ),
            end_datetime=ExpressionWrapper(
                F('date') + F('end_time'),
                output_field=models.DateTimeField()
            ),
            start_local_datetime=AtTimeZone(F('start_datetime', timezone='Europe/Berlin')
        )
```

The above is for a model with the initial fields of: `date`, `start_time`, and `end_time`.

Here are the docs regarding django's custom database functions. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions.
As of the start of 2022, the docs don't provide many examples on how to create custom database functions. This should help.

Comment: I was running into issues using this, but it was inspiration for the solution I found. I wrote a gist about it here: https://gist.github.com/rileypeterson/aaa827ae4cd6c691a0215c2f0b4dccd2

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use the library **pytz** (https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) to localize the naive datetime.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

tz = timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
naive_dt = datetime(2021, 9, 20, 17, 0)
localized_dt = tz.localize(naive_dt)
print(localized_dt)
```

Comment: I need the date localized within the SQL query, not in Python.

Comment: Also, Django deprecated pytz in favour of zoneinfo, so even if you wanted to convert a datetime object, you shouldn't use pytz in Django >= 4.